# Android listview and list view template

Tags: android

I'm begining android developing and I would ask a question:

```
 StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

I'm making here a adapter which layout is a builded layout.simple_list_item_1.xml and looks that:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

but if I want to make my own list item named "symply" in layout folder with this same xml code Android-Studio tells me that "Cannot resolve method symply". Of course i changed to

```
StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.symply, list);
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use R.layout.symply and not android.R.symply